# Xamarin Forms 4.1.0: Method not found: void .ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)

Tags: xamarin.forms

SOLUTION

[Solution here](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6787)

Or simply make sure that all projects in your solution using Xamarin Forms are updated.

Original Question

An upgrade to Xamarin Forms 4.1.0.555618 from 4.0.0.425677 is causing a Type Resolution exception and throwing the following error when I try to resolve a class:

```
Method not found: void .ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)
```

This doesn't happen with version 4.0.0.xxxx.

EDIT This only happens on Android (version 9.0/Pie), and works fine on iOS

If it helps I'm using [TinyIoCContainer](https://github.com/grumpydev/TinyIoC) to resolve any dependencies.

Comment: Clean your solution, delete all obj/bin folders and restart visual studio.

Comment: @Vahid No, that's not the problem.

Comment: Did you have add this issue to github?https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6787

Comment: Anything in this error, im having the same error now ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I forgot update Xamarin.Forms in Android project. The bug fixed after update.