# Xamarin crash: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void .ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2019

When I try to run my Xamarin app, I get this error in `InitializeComponent` of App.xaml.cs:

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: void .ResourceLoadingQuery.set_Instance(object)

I tried cleaning and rebuilding my solution, deleting my obj and bin folders, and restarting Visual Studio as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56898424/xamarin-forms-4-1-0-method-not-found-void-resourceloadingquery-set-instanceo) but that didn't seem to help...

edit: I also have a bunch of alleged compile errors in Resource.designer.cs which don't prevent the app from running, but maybe they are causing this problem?

[image]

Comment: Make sure that Android and iOS have same latest version as your forms project .

Comment: Latest version of what?

Comment: Aha, same version of Xamarin.Forms Nuget package reference. Thanks! :)

Comment: Did you try to create a new blank project then build it?

Comment: Error occurs if you have nothing between the ContentPage in the XAML remove the InitializeComponent(); and it should run smoothly

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem and the solution was to update the NuGet packages in all projects and I had updated only in the main project.

I was building only for android so I also needed to update the NuGet in the android project.

[image]

But after that I was getting another error message:

> error XF005: The $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for TripLog2.Android (v9.0) is less than the minimum required $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for Xamarin.Forms (10.0). You need to increase the $(TargetFrameworkVersion) for TripLog2.Android.

That was fixed by going into properties of android project and select verion 10 (from previously 9).

[image]

I tried selection 11 but that didn't work either and created another set of errors.

Note: I had to quit Visual Studio 2019 and start it again. Changing the version may requires updates and they don't take effect properly if VS is not restarted.

Answer (score 0):

My cause was an invalid App.xaml (Xamarin.Forms resources) file.